# How to sync different servers to GORM layer with cache enabled in Grails

Tags: caching, grails, grails-orm

I do have three instances of Grails app running in three different tomcat servers, sharing same DB (Oracle). I've enabled some of my domain classes with cache : true.

How can I sync all of my server cache while updating DB via one server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I sync all of my server cache while updating DB via one
> server.

You would need a shared distributed cache.  Ehcache would be one option (https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache-ehcache/).

Comment: How can I configure the distributed system for two or more nodes to make the caching properly?